# connecting to MongoDB cluster

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use this from the linux client which has all the sec groups intact

I am getting this error even though the cluster is running fine (checked locally on primary replica set), expert advice needed.

```
[ec2-user@mongo-client ~]$ mongo --host s-1/10.1.1.1:27017,10.1.1.2:27017,10.1.1.3:27017 admin
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
connecting to: s-1/10.1.1.1:27017,10.1.1.2:27017,10.1.1.3:27017/admin
2016-09-27T20:08:26.741+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] Starting new replica set monitor for s-1/10.1.1.1:27017,10.1.1.2:27017,10.1.1.3:27017
2016-09-27T20:08:26.741+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] starting
2016-09-27T20:08:31.738+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 10.1.1.2:27017, reason: errno:115 Operation now in progress
2016-09-27T20:08:36.738+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 10.1.1.3:27017, reason: errno:115 Operation now in progress
2016-09-27T20:08:41.738+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 10.1.1.1:27017, reason: errno:115 Operation now in progress
2016-09-27T20:08:41.738+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set s-1
2016-09-27T20:08:41.738+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] All nodes for set s-1 are down. This has happened for 1 checks in a row. Polling will stop after 29 more failed checks
2016-09-27T20:08:41.738+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: connect failed to replica set s-1/10.1.1.1:27017,10.1.1.2:27017,10.1.1.3:27017 :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:231:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```